# Can I run a program with input from the buffer?

Tags: c, linux, bash, latex, archlinux

I am looking to run a program on a target that is in memory.

For example I would like to call **LaTeX** on a set of characters in the memory instead of in file.

I realise I can set a file pointer in **C** to target memory and read/write to and from memory.

However I don't know if there is any way to pass LaTeX a file pointer or a wrapper to do so?

Running on **Arch Linux**, I don't care if I just get environment dependent solution for now - just need a starting point.

Comment: I am unaware of `latex` but your question seems to be talking something about bringing file to memory. That sounds pretty much like [`mmap(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) can do

Comment: You might be looking for `pipe`

Comment: Thanks Pipe or similar seems to be what I am looking for. I thought it would be standard as lots of uses! In my particular case I am going to have lots of standard template files that will have a couple of bytes changed in the buffer and then passed to another program. I don't want to have the overhead of a whole other file write to the hard disk instead of memory if I can help it :) I am reading the documentation now though not sure if it is an exact match but it may be the best thing available given the CPU is providing implementing virtual memory (I am looking at a hardware project)

Comment: Thanks heaps how do I upvote you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a file in /tmp. On most modern systems, /tmp is mounted using the "tmpfs" filesystem, which stores files in memory.

Maybe you don't want to rely on /tmp being a tmpfs. In that case, you can use [`memfd_create`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/memfd_create.2.html) to create a file   descriptor which is only stored in memory. If LaTeX needs a filename, you could make it open the file directly from your process, using `/proc/<your pid>/fd/<fd number>`.

A third solution is to use a pipe (which is what `popen` uses internally). This doesn't work if LaTeX wants to seek backwards or forwards in the file - you can't seek in a pipe. On the other hand, the pipe doesn't have to store the entire file at once.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, cheers. It also gives me a lot of direction on things to look into.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a conventional solution with [`popen`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/popen):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char buffer[] =
        "\\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}\n"
        "\\begin{document}This is the document.\n"
        "\\end{document}\n";
    FILE *fp = popen("latex", "w");
    if (!fp) perror("latex"), exit(1);
    fputs(buffer, fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```